# gedit text editor is getting crashed after copying the same text multiple times at same time (copy paste)

Tags: gedit, 23.10

gedit text editor is getting crashed after copying the same text multiple times at same time (copy paste), it shows scrambled text if I open the file after saving it and also it shows black screen sometimes. Kindly refer the attachment of screenshots.

What could be the issue ? I can't make a large files.

[image]

In my case, my file is not even 1 MB. It even crashes at 500 KB.

Comment: Not sure what this leads to except stress tests. gedit is a very liight duty text editor.  It may make sense to press the [Enter] key once in a while to avoid the distorted display issue.

Comment: If you want to make large amounts of text available and you don't care what's in it, then there are ways to create very large text files without touching an editor such as gedit.